# Convergence - Numerical Analysis

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

I am solving some exercises for our Arithmetical Analysis course (new one on our semester) and we're practicing with some old Calculus 1 & 2 stuff that I'm trying to bring in-front. There's an exercise that asks :

Prove that : $x_k = 1 + 2^{-k}$ converges linearly and that $x_k = 1 + 2^{-2^{k}} $converges quadraticaly.

Now, I know that a sequence converges linearly to L, if there exists a number $m \in (0,1)$ such that :

$\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{|x_{k+1} - L|}{|x_k - L|} = m $ and quadratically if $\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{|x_{k+1} - L|}{|x_k - L|^q} = m$ with $m>0, q=2$.

My question/problem is, that I seem to get my mind stuck on how to apply these on the given forms and continue. I would really appreciate if someone could elaborate in one of the examples, so that I could understand how I should work and apply it to the other one on my own.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Step 0: find $L$. Step 1: write down the quotient $\dfrac{x_{k+1} - L}{x_k - L}$ [resp. $\dfrac{x_{k+1} - L}{(x_k - L)^2}$] and simplify.

Comment: Thanks a lot .. My question was silly after all, just my mind bugged and was confused!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first.

$x_k=1+2^{-k}=1+\frac{1}{2^k}$

$\lim_{k \to +\infty}x_k=L=1$.

$\lim_{k\to +\infty}|\frac{x_{k+1}-1}{x_k-1}|=\frac{1}{2}=m$

For the second

$x_k=1+\frac{1}{2^{2^k}}$

so $\lim_{k\to+\infty}x_k=1$

$\lim_{k\to+\infty}|\frac{x_{k+1}-1}{(x_k-1)^2}|=1$

qed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. My mind was bugged, so you got me un-confused !